# Ant and annotated junit tests

Tags: java, macos, ant, junit

I have the following test class in ./src/com.example.package.tests

```
public class CardTest {
    @Test
    public void testCardCompareWithSameValue() throws Exception {
        Card card1 = new Card(Card.COLOR.CLUBS, 4);
        Card card2 = new Card(Card.COLOR.SPADES, 4);

        Card.MATCH_TYPE match = card1.compareCard(card2);

        assertEquals("The returned match must be of enum type Card.MATCH_TYPE.VALUE",
            Card.MATCH_TYPE.VALUE, match);
    }
}
```

I have placed junit-4.7.jar in ./lib

and have the following ./build.xml

```
<project name="Project" basedir="." default="main">

    <property name="src.dir" value="src" />
    <property name="build.dir" value="build" />
    <property name="classes.dir" value="${build.dir}/classes" />
    <property name="jar.dir" value="${build.dir}/jar" />
    <property name="lib.dir" value="lib" />
    <property name="main-class" value="com.example.package.gui.Main" />
    <property name="report.dir" value="${build.dir}/junitreport" />

    <path id="classpath">
        <fileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="**/*.jar" />
    </path>


    <path id="application" location="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar"/>


    <target name="clean">
        <delete dir="${build.dir}" />
    </target>

    <target name="compile">
        <mkdir dir="${classes.dir}" />
        <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${classes.dir}" classpathref="classpath" />
        <copy todir="${classes.dir}">
            <fileset dir="${src.dir}" excludes="**/*.java" />
        </copy>
    </target>

    <target name="jar" depends="junit">
        <mkdir dir="${jar.dir}" />
        <jar destfile="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar" basedir="${classes.dir}" excludes="**/*Test.class">
            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main-class}" />
            </manifest>
        </jar>

    </target>


    <target name="junit" depends="compile">
        <mkdir dir="${report.dir}" />
        <junit printsummary="yes" haltonfailure="yes" showoutput="yes">
            <classpath>
                <path refid="classpath" />
                <path location="${classes.dir}" />
                <path refid="application" />
            </classpath>

            <formatter type="xml" />

            <batchtest fork="yes">
                <fileset dir="${src.dir}" includes="*Test.java" />
            </batchtest>
        </junit>
    </target>

    <target name="junitreport" depends="junit">
        <junitreport todir="${report.dir}">
            <fileset dir="${report.dir}" includes="TEST-*.xml" />
            <report todir="${report.dir}" />
        </junitreport>
    </target>


    <target name="run" depends="jar">
        <java classname="${main-class}" fork="true" >
            <classpath>
                <path refid="classpath" />
                <path refid="application" />
            </classpath>
        </java>
    </target>

    <target name="clean-build" depends="clean,jar" />

    <target name="main" depends="clean,run" />

</project>
```

Why does ant not run my junit tests? When I check the report it says that there were 0 tests.

I am using OS X Yosemite and installed Ant via the binary download.

Edit: Tested with ubuntu as well, no change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was what worked, a combination of @dawid-w 's and @dkatzel 's answers.

```
        <batchtest fork="yes" skipnontests="yes" todir="${report.dir}">
            <fileset dir="${classes.dir}" />
        </batchtest>
```

Comment: If you don't put a `todir` attribute, it should have written the reports to the directory containing the `build.xml` file. Did you see it there? If this works, I'm glad you got it working.

Comment: Yes, but the stuff that made it found the tests was the removal of the includes="" attribute.

Answer (score 3):

When you run `<junit>`, you want to refer to the compiled test ***class files*** and not the test Java ***source files***.

I recommend to put your regular sources and test sources into two different directories, then compile them into two different directories. We use the Maven directory standards:

- `src/main/java` - Location of the regular source files.
- `src/main/resources` - Location of the *resources* (XML and JSON files that go into the jar).
- `src/test/java` - Location of the test source files.
- `src/test/resources` - Location of the resources needed for testing.
- `target/classes` - Where regular source class files are compiled.
- `target/test-classes` - Where test class files are compiled.

Example:

```
<target name="compile">
    <javac srcdir="src/main/java"
        destdir="target/classes">
        <classpath ref="main.classpath"/>
    </javac>
</target>

<target name="package"
    depends="compile">
    <jar destfile="target/${ant.project.name}.jar">
        <fileset dir="target/classes"/>
        <fileset dir="src/main/resources"/>
    </jar>
</target>

<target name="compile-test"
    depends="compile">

    <!-- Classpath must include the main.classpath from -->
    <!-- above, the test.classpath which will include   -->
    <!-- "junit.jar", and finally the compiled classes  -->
    <!-- from target/classes. Not 100% sure if this is  -->
    <!-- the correct way to specify it, but it's close. -->
    <javac srcdir="src/test/java"
        destdir="target/test-classes">
        <classpath>
             <path ref="main.classpath"/>
             <path ref="test.classpath"/>
             <path location="target/classes"/>
        <classpath>
    </javac>
</target>

<junit printsummary="yes"
    haltonfailure="yes"
    showoutput="yes">
    <classpath>
        <path refid="main.classpath" />
        <path refid="test.classpath" />
        <path location="${classes.dir}" />
    </classpath>

        <!-- Batchtest is pointing to the classes-->
        <formatter type="xml" />
        <batchtest fork="yes">
            <fileset dir="${target/test-classes}"/>
        </batchtest>
    </junit>
</target>
```

Comment: I changed the <batchtest><fileset> to point at the classes, but it still does not work.

Thanks for the suggestion on project structure but when I tried to convert to it a lot of stuff got messed up so I am going to stay with my current one for now.

Comment: One more thing to try "Run this with `ant -d`. That will print out a lot of stuff, so you need to save it to a file, or start out with a clean terminal and a large terminal buffer. You can see if that `batchtest` line is actually be executed or that `junit` task is being executed and what's going on.

Comment: Is this the output from the `-d` debug flag? Can you see what's in the directory `/Users/richard/_GIT/slot-machine/build/classes`? See if there are any files that match `*Test.class` suffix? Also, update your question to show the changes in the build.xml file.

Comment: I posted my own answer, it was a combination of yours, the other answer that was given and some docs i read.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Ant JUnit Task documentation](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junit.html) you have to tell the `batchtest` where to put the test reports using the `todir` attribute.  Otherwise it will write them to the current working directory.

```
<batchtest fork="yes"  todir="${report.dir}">
            <fileset dir="${src.dir}" includes="*Test.java" />
        </batchtest>
```

Should work.

Also check the current working directory to see if you have a bunch of TEST-*.xml files

Comment: It does output the TESTS-TestSuits.xml into build/junitreport where it is supposed to so that seems to be right.